# Excel: remove text after last period

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using Microsoft 365 Excel.

How do I remove all text to the right of the last full stop in a cell?

I'd like to crop the cell to maintain the phrase's grammar.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this article](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3298-excel-remove-after-first-last-space.html), I used:

`=LEFT(D2,FIND("^^",SUBSTITUTE(D2,".","^^",LEN(D2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2,".",""))))-1)`

where `D2` contained the text to work on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,RIGHT(A1,MATCH(,0/(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,ROW($1:$99)))="."),)),)
```

[image]